# NodeJS Assets Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js

Good morning!

I'd like to know if serving static files (css, images, and js) through the manifest pattern with Nodejs + Express is the smartest way or if there is a higher-performance shape.

I'm using Nunjucks as the template engine.

I used three archives of demonstrators created by Gulp:

```
assets = {
    styles: function () {
        var stylesManifest = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./dist/styles.manifest.json', 'utf8'));

        Object.keys(stylesManifest).map(function(value, index) {
            stylesManifest[value] = "/dist/" + stylesManifest[value];
        });

        return stylesManifest;
    },
    scripts: function () {
        var scriptsManifest = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./dist/scripts.manifest.json', 'utf8'));

        Object.keys(scriptsManifest).map(function(value, index) {
            scriptsManifest[value] = "/dist/" + scriptsManifest[value];
        });

        return scriptsManifest;
    },
    images: function () {
        var imagesManifest = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./dist/images.manifest.json', 'utf8'));

        Object.keys(imagesManifest).map(function(value, index) {
            imagesManifest[value] = "/dist/" + imagesManifest[value];
        });

        return imagesManifest;
    }
};

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    app.locals.assets = {
        css: assets.styles(),
        js: assets.scripts(),
        images: assets.images()
    };
    next();
});
```

If anyone knows, help. Thanks!